# Union all where date clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union-all, having-clause

My Query

```
SELECT RoomType, date FROM Superior WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30')AND (Avail > '0')
UNION
SELECT RoomType, date FROM Deluxe WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30')AND (Avail > '0')
UNION
SELECT RoomType, date FROM SuperDeluxe WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30')AND (Avail > '0')
ORDER BY date
HAVING COUNT(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Getting syntax error near '`HAVING COUNT(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY)`

My goal is to get results for room type with dates and Avail greater than 3 days

** In Table for Superior and Deluxe for date 2012-06-29 Avail=0, for SuperDeluxe all date is Avail

In this case my result should only display SuperDeluxe as Availability but

```
**RoomType**    **date**
Superior        2012-06-26
Superior        2012-06-27
Superior        2012-06-28
Deluxe          2012-06-26
Deluxe          2012-06-27
Deluxe          2012-06-28
SuperDeluxe     2012-06-26
SuperDeluxe     2012-06-27
SuperDeluxe     2012-06-28
SuperDeluxe     2012-06-29
```

Yes it is MySQL, I am just trying to proof to myself that i can get this done helping my Uncle. As you know I am not a seasonal just a beginner. You guessed right, all 3 tables are ambiguous. I have another field Avail which keep track of number of rooms available. As a booking is complete, it auto calculate available rooms.

My current queries are using option selection of Room type which can only generate availability for a room type for each query. With the above, I planned to have 1 query and generate any room type that is available in the date range. The problem I have when I use the above union query, the result I get also include one of the date in the range that availability is = 0

I was trying something like this

```
SELECT RoomType, COUNT( date )
FROM Superior
WHERE date >= '2012-06-26'
  AND date < '2012-06-30'
  AND Avail > '0'
UNION
SELECT RoomType, COUNT( date )
FROM Deluxe
WHERE date >= '2012-06-26'
  AND date < '2012-06-30'
  AND Avail > '0'
UNION
SELECT RoomType, COUNT( date )
FROM SuperDeluxe
WHERE date >= '2012-06-26'
  AND date < '2012-06-30'
  AND Avail > '0'
GROUP BY date
HAVING COUNT( 4 )
```

Looks like i am getting closer. I tried MAX( date ) it gives date that has 4 rows but it still displaying 1 row of the room type that Avail is > 0

I also tried HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT date ) =4
Results still display field date with rows not equal to 4

Comment: What database product are you using? MySQL? Also, this smells of attribute splitting - why are there 3 seemingly identical tables? Why not just 1 table with an additional column specifying Superior, Deluxe or SuperDeluxe?

Comment: Show us table definition and sample data. What is `Availability`, a 0 or 1 flag? Is it an integer that describes available days?

Comment: As you have a where clause in each of your 3 selects, simply remove the `HAVING` statement.

Answer (score 4):

`HAVING` only works with `GROUP BY` (to filter groups), but you don't have groups in play.

You need a straightforward `WHERE` clause in each select, and a wrapping select you can order:

```
select * from (
    SELECT RoomType, date 
    FROM Superior
    WHERE date >= '2012-06-26' 
    AND date < '2012-06-30'
    AND Avail > 3 -- specify avail range here
  UNION
    SELECT RoomType, date
    FROM Deluxe
    WHERE date >= '2012-06-26' 
    AND date < '2012-06-30'
    AND Avail > 3 -- specify avail range here
  UNION
    SELECT RoomType, date
    FROM SuperDeluxe
    WHERE date >= '2012-06-26' 
    AND date < '2012-06-30'
    AND Avail > 3 -- specify avail range here
) results
ORDER BY date
```

I would seriously consider merging the data into one table and adding a column to distinguish the three booking types, rather than having more tables. Not only will it make your queries sane, but when you get a new booking type, you don't have to create another table.

Comment: Not sure if that will sove the problem as the specs are rather vague but it seems on the right direction. You don't need to wrap this query in a nested subquery though.